# openstack issue a token with no expire time

Tags: openstack, identity, openstack-keystone

I'm developing a micro-service which needs to connect to my `openstack` via REST API:

I'm using this command in `CLI` to create an access token (X-Auth-Token):

```
openstack --os-system-scope all token issue
```

Is it possible to create the admin token with no expire time? And apply restriction on request ip address?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you could find a way to have tokens for ever.
but you might like to check token less auth:

https://docs.openstack.org/keystoneauth/latest/api/keystoneauth1.identity.v3.tokenless_auth.html